# Telerik RadToolTip won't hide when empty

Tags: wpf, silverlight, telerik, tooltip

I have a list I want to show in a tooltip, but when it is empty the tooltip should not exist.  However, when it is empty it still shows a very small, empty box.

```
<t:RadDropDownButton.ToolTip>
 <t:RadToolTip Visibility="{Binding MyList, Converter={StaticResource EmptyListToCollapsedConverter}}"
               Content="{Binding MyList}">
    <t:RadToolTip.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </t:RadToolTip.ContentTemplate>
  </t:RadToolTip>
</t:RadDropDownButton.ToolTip>
```

What's wrong with this?  It happens anywhere RadToolTip is used.  Setting its Visibility doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this, but it turned out I was using the control incorrectly.  The tool tip was supposed to be applied in a different place.  Sorry that's all I can remember!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would happen even if you just the Tooltip class. MS does not assume the tooltip should not show. If you set the tooltip property of an element and want to hide/suppress it then set the attached [ToolTipService.IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.isenabled.aspx) to false.